# List model not returning data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the code below which loads on edit mode. but when i get the infor back to server it dosent return any rows any ideas why. the method does go into the post method below. this will be a update method in edit mode.

```
    @model List<SubjectSuggestionModel>
    @using Telerik.Sitefinity.UI.MVC
    @using Telerik.Sitefinity.UI.MVC.Helpers
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                dataSource: { pageSize: 20 }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <fieldset>
            <table id="grid">
              <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-sortable="false">
                                Subject ID
                            </th>
                            <th data-sortable="false">
                                Suggestion order
                            </th>
                            <th data-field="QuestionText">
                                Suggested subject
                            </th>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                @using (Html.BeginFormSitefinity("editSubjectSuggestions", "editSubjectSuggestions"))
                {
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                   <tbody>
                        @foreach (var i in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => i.subject_id, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                                </td>
                                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => i.suggestion_order)
                                </td>
                                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => i.suggested_subject_id)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>

                }
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="confirm" runat="server" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Action methods

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult editSubjectSuggestions(List<SubjectSuggestionModel> models)
{
    return View("subjectSuggestion", prsubList.getSubjectSuggestionsList(
               Convert.ToInt32(Session["subjectID"].ToString())));
}
```

Comment: Create `[HttpGet]` action and push the model.

Comment: I have added a HttpGet but i am looking to post the data on the page back which is not working,

Answer (score 2):

Using a `foreach`loop generates duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and duplicate `name` attributes without indexers which cannot be bound to a collection. You must use a `for` loop or a custom `EditorTemplate` for the type.

Using a `for` loop

```
<tbody>
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].subject_id, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
      <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].suggestion_order)</td>
      <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].suggested_subject_id)</td>
    </tr>
  }
</tbody>
```

Using an `EditorTemplate`

In `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SubjectSuggestionModel.cshtml`

```
@model SubjectSuggestionModel
<tr>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.subject_id, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.suggestion_order)</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.suggested_subject_id)</td>
</tr>
```

and in the main view

```
<tbody>
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
</tbody>
```

Comment: this still doesnot work, its not sending the information backt o the server, if you add that on the page then it wount display all the text.

Comment: A course it works. Your must be doing something else wrong. Note also you have invalid html (the `@Html.BeginForm()` `@Html.ValidationSummary()` cannot be a child objects of `<table>` - you need to put the whole table inside the `<form>` tags) and `runat="server"` is web forms, not MVC)